# Pandas: Flattening heirarchical data into a new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data that looks like this

```
    A    B    C    
0   a0   b0   0,0  
1   a1   b1   1,1  
2   a2   b2   2,2  
3   a0   b1   0,1
4   a0   b2   0,2
...
```

for an analysis it ended up becoming

```
      C
B     b0    b1    b2
A
a0    0,0   0,1   0,2
a1    1,0   1,1   1,2
a2    2,0   2,1   2,2
```

where the values of `C` correspond to `<a_index>,<b_index>`.

from this structure, how do I go back to the first?

Comment: Use `df.stack().reset_index()`?

Comment: Thanks @Zero but why do I have to stack to go from hierarchical to flat?